# How to link two scene nodes in Ogre?

Tags: nodes, transformation, ogre

I know it's an unusual way to search this kind of feature, but **is it possible to set an automatic transformations link from one SceneNode to an other ?**

For example, if I link a SceneNode A   to a SceneNode B, and if I apply a translation on the SceneNode A, the SceneNode B has to receive the same translation.
As if SceneNode B was the child of SceneNode A. But it's not.

?

Comment: what stops you from making B a child of A?

Comment: In fact, i need an independent bounding box computing. If there is a parent link, the associated boundingbox will grow with its childs.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is this:

```
::Ogre::SceneNode* ChildSceneNode = parentNode.createChildSceneNode()
```

Then the child scene node inherits the transformations from the parent.
Move the parent and the child moves too.

Answer (score 0):

If a parent-child relation is no option for you (and you said so in your comments), then you are stuck with handling it yourself by either:

**a)** Keeping track of all changes of the node you want to follow yourself

**b)** Using an Ogre::Node::Listener that you can attach to the node you want to track (the "parent") and the once an update event is fired, you update the tracking ("child") node as well:

[API: setListener(..) of Ogre::Scenenode](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1Node.html#ac958f0d4fad0970aa65bdd0f86de6781)

[API: nodeUpdated(..) of Ogre::Node::Listener](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1Node_1_1Listener.html#a4038dce943694bf4577fc99aa76c99ec%20%22nodeUpdated%28%29%20of%20Ogre%3a%3aListener)